# lapply a paste0 function over a list

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply, paste

### **Data with the reproducible example**

I have the following list

```
library(arrangements)

a <- list(
arrangements::combinations(x = 5, k = 5),
arrangements::combinations(x = 5, k = 4),
arrangements::combinations(x = 4, k = 4))
```

Which looks like this:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    5
[3,]    1    2    4    5
[4,]    1    3    4    5
[5,]    2    3    4    5

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
```

### **What I need**

I would like to use some function over each row of each element of the list `a` (i.e. `[[1]], [[2]], [[3]]`) so that the output would look something like the following:

```
[[1]]
"F1 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +5"

[[2]]
"F2 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4" 
"F3 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 5" 
"F4 =~ 1 + 2 + 4 + 5" 
"F5 =~ 1 + 3 + 4 + 5"
"F6 =~ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5"

[[3]]
"F7 =~ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5"
```

### **What I have managed to do so far and where I am stuck**

I have managed to produce the output that I need for individual elements of the list. For example, the below for loop produces the output that I need but only for the second element of list `a`.

```
z <- list(
arrangements::combinations(x = 5, k = 4))

qq <- vector(mode = "character", length = 0L)

    for(i in 1:5) {
            qq[i] <- paste0("F", i+1, sep = " =~ ", paste(z[[1]][i, ], collapse=" + "))
}   

qq

[1] "F2 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4" "F3 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 5" "F4 =~ 1 + 2 + 4 + 5" "F5 =~ 1 + 3 + 4 + 5"
[5] "F6 =~ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5"
```

I was not able to write the for loop for the whole list because each element of the list has different dimensions and I get an error that the subscript is out of bounds. Also, I cannot tackle individual elements of list `a` because it is an example and a list might be much larger, so I need a way to automate it.

I suspect that this can be done by combining `lapply` and `apply`  but I just cannot figure out how to make it work. For example, here `lapply` and `apply` work together but I just cannot figure out how to make them output what I need.

```
lapply(a, function(x) apply(a[[2]], 1, paste, collapse=""))
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Map` with `sprintf` -

```
nr <- sapply(a, nrow)
Map(function(x, y) sprintf('F%d = ~%s', (y - nrow(x) + 1):y, 
                   apply(x, 1,paste0, collapse = '+')), a, cumsum(nr))

#[[1]]
#[1] "F1 = ~1+2+3+4+5"

#[[2]]
#[1] "F2 = ~1+2+3+4" "F3 = ~1+2+3+5" "F4 = ~1+2+4+5" "F5 = ~1+3+4+5"
#[5] "F6 = ~2+3+4+5"

#[[3]]
#[1] "F7 = ~1+2+3+4"
```

`nr` is used to count number of rows in each matrix of `a`. In `Map` we pass the list of matrix `a` and cumulative sum of `nr` which will tell us where each sequence is going to end (`cumsum(nr)`). In the function we use this information to get the start of the sequence (`(y - nrow(x) + 1)`) and rowwise paste the matrix to get the required output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate it. Could you please briefly outline what the code does, so as to enhance my personal learning of the logic behind it? Thank you in advance

Comment: @PsychometStats I added some explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `reformulate()`.

```
b <- lapply(a, \(i) 
            apply(i, 1, \(x) 
                  Reduce(paste0, as.character(reformulate(as.character(x))))))
b <- Map(\(x, y) paste(sprintf('F%s=', seq(b[[y]]) + x), b[[y]]),
    c(0, cumsum(lengths(b)[-length(b)])), seq(b))
```

Alternative approach using `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral()` which might have benefits over `arrangements::combinations` with its `FUN=` argument. (*Note:* Just replace `comboGeneral()` with `combn()` for a purely base R option).

```
library(RcppAlgos)
b <- Map(\(x, m) comboGeneral(as.character(x), m, FUN=\(i) 
                       Reduce(paste0, as.character(reformulate(i)))),
         lapply(c(5, 5, 4), seq), c(5, 4, 4))
b <- Map(\(x, y) paste(sprintf('F%s=', seq(b[[y]]) + x), b[[y]]),
    c(0, cumsum(lengths(b)[-length(b)])), seq(b))
```

*Results:*

```
b
# [[1]]
# [1] "F1= ~1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "F2= ~1 + 2 + 3 + 4" "F3= ~1 + 2 + 3 + 5" "F4= ~1 + 2 + 4 + 5"
# [4] "F5= ~1 + 3 + 4 + 5" "F6= ~2 + 3 + 4 + 5"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "F7= ~1 + 2 + 3 + 4"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you need. The trick is to produce a second list `a2` consisting of single rows, so that the numbering of F works properly...

```
a2 <- unlist(lapply(a, apply, 1, identity, simplify = FALSE), #separates the rows
             recursive = FALSE)                               #keeps as list

relist(sapply(seq_along(a2),                                  #to get overall id no i
              function(i) paste0("F", i, " =~ ", 
                                 paste(a2[i][[1]], collapse=" + "))),
       lapply(a, rowSums))                                    #a list for relisting by

[[1]]
[1] "F1 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5"

[[2]]
[1] "F2 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4" "F3 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 5" "F4 =~ 1 + 2 + 4 + 5" 
    "F5 =~ 1 + 3 + 4 + 5" "F6 =~ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5"

[[3]]
[1] "F7 =~ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4"
```